# FFmpeg: possible to apply filter to only part of a video file while transcoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a short 3:00 min clip that is only flipped left to right for about :30 sec in the middle.

So if the whole thing were flipped left to right, I would just want to apply:

`ffmpeg -i 3min.mp4 -vf hflip flipped_3min.mp4`

But since it's only partly flipped, is there a way, in a single ffmpeg command, to apply a time segment for that hflip filter (1:30-2:00)?

I am looking for some documentation on this and can't find any thing of the sort, am wondering if it's just not possible in FFmpeg or not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### How do I flip only a subsection of a video using `ffmpeg`?

Here, [`-filter_complex`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1) is your friend, as it can create chains of filtered input. We will still be using the `hflip` filter mentioned in the question in the filtergraph.

You can apply to a subsection like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=0:duration=90[a];\
[0:v]trim=start=90:duration=30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];\
[b]hflip[c];\
[a][c]concat[d];\
[0:v]trim=start=120:duration=60,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[e];\
[d][e]concat[out1]" -map [out1] flip.mp4
```

One line for easy copy + pasting:

```
ffmpeg  -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=0:duration=90[a];[0:v]trim=start=90:duration=30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[b]hflip[c];[a][c]concat[d];[0:v]trim=start=120:duration=60,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[e];[d][e]concat[out1]" -map [out1] flip.mp4
```

## Explanation:

Using a filtergraph is a bit like creating a chain of actions, and there is a nice visual explanation<sup>1</sup> of this in the ['Filtering Introduction' section](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) of the filters documentation. Filters work with **inputs** - that's the bit you see before the filter, eg `[0:v]` (video of first input stream) or `[a]` (a created output named `a`) - and **outputs**. That is to say, an **input** or **inputs** are transformed according to a `filter` and then output either as an **output** or **outputs**.

We have a simple set of actions here, and if we go through those in sequence we can build up a filtergraph of inputs and outputs.

### Segments

Create 3 segments of video (from input `[0:v]`) using `trim`:

- First segment (90 seconds), do nothing to (output as `[a]`)
- Second segment (30 seconds), `hflip` and `setpts` to avoid duration issues (output trim as `[b]` and pass that to `hflip` to output as `[c]`)

These two are then `concat`ed together to make the output `[a]+[c] -> [d]` (duration: 120 s)

- Third segment (60 seconds), set PTS again (output as `[e]`)

Join segments to make output `[d] + [e] -> [out1]`, and `-map` that to final output in file.

That gives you a video of the same duration as the original (180 s), but with a section of 30 seconds in the middle which are horizontally flipped<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>:

### Visual representation from [`ffmpeg` filters documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction)

> In `libavfilter`, a filter can have multiple inputs and multiple outputs. To illustrate the sorts of things that are possible, we consider the following filtergraph.

```
                [main]
input --> split ---------------------> overlay --> output
            |                             ^
            |[tmp]                  [flip]|
            +-----> crop --> vflip -------+
```

> This filtergraph splits the input stream in two streams, then sends one stream through the crop filter and the vflip filter, before merging it back with the other stream by overlaying it on top.

---

<sup><sup>2</sup> Tested using `ffmpeg version N-72939-g5b0f55a`</sup>

Comment: How to speed up only the middle of the video using the same method?

Answer (score 17):

[image: Horizontal flipping occurs between 2-3 seconds in this example.]
<sub>Horizontal flipping occurs between 2-3 seconds in this example.</sub>

Some filters have timeline support via the [enable option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing).

You can see a list of filters and if they have timeline support with `ffmpeg -filters`. A "`T`" preceding the filter name indicates that it supports timeline editing. If your desired filter does not have timeline support then update your `ffmpeg` as filters sometimes get updated to support this. Otherwise, use the trim filters as explained in the other answer.

**`ffmpeg` example:**

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "hflip=enable='between(t,90,120)'" -c:a copy output
```

**`ffplay` example:**

```
ffplay -vf "hflip=enable='between(t,90,120)'" input
```